# Need help regarding .forEach()

Tags: javascript

Can I ask what are the differences between these 2 codes, even though they give the same output?

Code example 1:

```js
const veggies = ['broccoli', 'spinach', 'cauliflower', 'broccoflower'];

const politelyDecline = (veg) => {
  console.log('No ' + veg + ' please. I will have pizza with extra cheese.');
}

function declineEverything(arr) {
  arr.forEach(politelyDecline)
}

declineEverything(veggies)
```

Code example 2:

```js
const veggies = ['broccoli', 'spinach', 'cauliflower', 'broccoflower'];

const politelyDecline = (veg) => {
  console.log('No ' + veg + ' please. I will have pizza with extra cheese.');
}

function declineEverything(arr) {
  arr.forEach(veggie => {
    politelyDecline(veggie)
  })
}

declineEverything(veggies)
```

Comment: They are the same. Passing a function as the array.forEach is shorthand for 'call this function and use the iterator value as the argument'

Comment: Inside your second code you can make use of closures. There is one more function invovled so anything you can write stuff inside the curly braces like console.log etc.

Answer (score 2):

In the first approach, the `politelyDecline` function gets [two additional arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#syntax). The index of the current element and the array being iterated.

```
const politelyDecline = (veg, i, array) => {
  console.log(veg, i, JSON.stringify(array))
}

// you can see it better with declaration syntax using "arguments"
function politelyDecline(veg) {
  console.log(arguments)
}
```

```js
const veggies = ['broccoli', 'spinach', 'cauliflower', 'broccoflower'];

const politelyDecline = (veg, i, array) => {
  console.log(veg, i, JSON.stringify(array))
}

function declineEverything(arr) {
  arr.forEach(politelyDecline)
}

declineEverything(veggies)
```

Also, if you created `politelyDecline` with a function declaration syntax instead of a arrow function expression, the behavior of `this` changes inside it. In the following code, a `broccoliCounter` object is passed as a second argument to `forEach`. This object is used whenever `this` is called inside the callback. Here, it increments a property if the `veg` has the string `"brocc"` in it.

```
function politelyDecline(veg) {
  if (veg.includes("brocc") )
    this.count++
}

function declineEverything(arr) {
  const broccoliCounter = { count: 0 }
  arr.forEach(politelyDecline, broccoliCounter)
  console.log(broccoliCounter)
}
```

```js
const veggies = ['broccoli', 'spinach', 'cauliflower', 'broccoflower'];

function politelyDecline(veg) {
  if (veg.includes("brocc") )
    this.count++
}

function declineEverything(arr) {
  const broccoliCounter = { count: 0 }
  arr.forEach(politelyDecline, broccoliCounter)
  console.log(broccoliCounter)
}

declineEverything(veggies)
```

Comment: arr.forEach((veggie, i) => {
politelyDecline(veggie)
console.log(i)
})

You can have an index in second example also

Comment: @Aniket the difference is the arguments passed to the `politelyDecline` function.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there is no difference between both codes.
The only difference is the scope of writing a logic while running that second code foreach.

For e.g.

In the first example, you are just looping through that array but you can not do anything while looping. And if you want to do some operation while looping through, you have to follow the second code example approach like this

```
const veggies = ['broccoli', 'spinach', 'cauliflower', 'broccoflower'];

const politelyDecline = (veg) => {
      console.log('No ' + veg + ' please. I will have pizza with extra cheese.');
}
    
function declineEverything(arr){

arr.forEach(veggie => {
   politelyDecline(veggie)
   // see this console it will run everytime
   console.log('here')
})

}

declineEverything(veggies)
```

Comment: Why can't you do anything in the first one? You just do it in the callback function rather than inline to the loop

Comment: If you add a callback then it will be the same as the second one. He is not using call back in his first example that's why he can not write any logic while traversing that loop

Comment: I understand that. The wording you used isn't accurate. _but you can not do anything while traversing_ -- they are functionally the same just different ways of writing the same function.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically doing the same thing in the two codes. However, the first one is using direct reference to each item. And, the second one is doing it inside of an anonymous function. However, since both are accessing the same array and aren't in any way changing the content, the output remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the First example you are passing `politelyDecline` function to `.forEach()` as a callback. While in the Second example you are passing a anonymous fat-arrow function to `.forEach()` and calling `politelyDecline` in the body of that anonymous function!

In only this situation writing code both ways behaves similarly. However the resource consumption can still be slightly different.